# Why does a Python Iterator need an iter method that simply returns self?

Tags: python, iterator

I understand that the standard says that it does but I am trying to find the underlying reason for this.

If it simply always returns `self` what is the need for it?

You clearly always have access to the object since you are calling `iter` on that object, so what's the need for having it?

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Imagine you want to write code that iterates over any kind of iterable. Normally you'd just write a `for` statement or comprehension, but let's instead explicitly do what `for` does under the covers, to make things more obvious:

```
i = iter(iterable)
while True:
    try:
        val = next(i)
    except StopIteration:
        break
    else:
        do_stuff(val)
```

If you don't do that first line, your code won't work with lists, strings, tuples, or anything but iterator.

But if you do that first line, well, `iter(iterable)` had better return an iterator, or your code won't work with iterators.

---

You may wonder why `iter` couldn't just do the right thing without this? After all, it *does* have magic in it to create an iterator when given an object that has a `__len__` and `__getitem__` but no `__iter__`, so why couldn't it also have magic to just return its argument if it has a `__next__` but no `__iter__`? That's a language-design issue, but generally, Python tries to have as little magic as possible. The magic to make not-quite-sequences iterable was necessary because such sequences existed (in widespread third-party code) before the iteration protocol was added to the language, and it would be too hard to remove for the small benefit of simplifying things.

Comment: @delnan: The answer already says: "you usually just use a `for` statement (or comprehension)… which does this code under the covers." Does that need to be made clearer?

Comment: I think I just missed that part. Which may either indicate that it needs to be highlighted more, or that I need to read more carefully :-)

Comment: @delnan: OK, is the new version better?

Comment: It's certainly harder to miss when one just skims over it. But that's just icing on the cake, the answer was already great from its first revision. +1

Comment: makes sense now - espc. your last point about the difficulty to remove vs. the benefit of simplifying. Thanks for a thorough explanation.

Answer (score 2):

`for` loops should work with iterables, so `for i in something:` automatically calls `iter(something)` to get an iterator and iterates over said iterator. Now if iterators weren't iterable too (i.e. did not define `__iter__`), you couldn't use `for` loops with iterators, i.e.:

```
items = [1, 2, 3]
# this would work
for item in items: pass
# this wouldn't
it = iter(items)
for item in it: pass
```

Therefore, iterators should be iterables too. The alternative, "somehow detecting" iterators and not calling `iter` on them, is hacky and fragile (how would you decide that?).

Comment: The way you'd decide that—as proposed (and rejected) about once or twice a year on python-ideas—is simple: If `i.__iter__()` raises an `AttributeError`, before doing the fallback to index-based iteration, first check if `i.__next__` exists and, if so, return `i`.

Comment: @abarnert And isn't that, for lack of a better wording, "hacky and fragile"? ;-)

Comment: The change would be a few lines of simple and obvious code in the implementation of `iter`. Multiple people have written patches which work and pass the full test suite on the first try, which implies that it's not that brittle. The real problem is that it makes the language too "magical", making it easier to type but harder to learn and hold in your head.

Comment: @abarnert "magical" is one of the things I meant by "hacky". As for brittle, I can see at least one undesirable consequence: A genuine bug in a nontrivial `__iter__`, which happens to manifest itself as `AttributeError`, would lead to Python complaining about the lack of `__next__` on what should be an *iterable*. I've had trouble with shitty diagnostics from a similar "exception X means it's not an Y duck" strategy: `print(*y())` where `def y(): raise TypeError; yield` claims that the `argument after * must be a sequence, not generator`.

Comment: Actually, I'm pretty sure CPython actually checks for the presence of `__iter__` before calling it, meaning that _wouldn't_ happen… but then some other implementation that followed the same _documented_ rules but in a different way might give you a different error for that case… which is not a good thing. Next time someone suggests this on python-ideas, bring that up. :)

Comment: @abarnert The issue is not only whether some part of CPython checks for the presence of `__iter__` separately from calling it, but also whether the code responsible for the error message will be able to differentiate between errors happening *before* `__iter__` is invoked and during. The `*gen_with_typeerror()` problem is caused by the argument unpacking code using `PySequence_Tuple()` and taking any TypeError from that to mean "not an iterable". I'm not an expert on the C-API, but I think `PyObject_GetIter` also muddies the two causes of "can't get an iterator".

Comment: But the code to do the check-and-fallback would be inside `PyObject_GetIter`, not in code that calls it. So, the fact that it muddles the two error cases externally wouldn't make a difference. You can see the C-API `tp_iter` fallback [here](http://hg.python.org/cpython/file/default/Objects/abstract.c#l2644) and the Python-object `__iter__` code [here](http://hg.python.org/cpython/file/default/Objects/typeobject.c#l5907). In both cases, you can distinguish between `tp_iter`/`__iter__` not existing vs. existing and raising.

Comment: I believe [this](http://pastebin.com/tKV0Rvre) is a reasonably faithful pure-Python port of the entire machinery involved in calling `iter`, and [this](http://pastebin.com/GmucU5gK) is how you'd patch it to allow iterators to not define `__iter__`. (Assuming you don't want C iterators to fall back to `tp_next`, and you don't care about the whole iternext optimization/protection mechanism, and you care about a pure-Python port of CPython's C code more than something like, say, PyPy's code…)

Answer (score 0):

It's so `for` loops and other code that needs to work with iterables can unconditionally call `iter` on the thing they're iterating over, rather than treating iterators and other iterables separately. In particular, non-iterators might reasonably have a method called `next`, and we want to be able to distinguish them from iterators.

Comment: It's not really because non-iterators might have a method called `next`. (That _is_ probably why `next` was renamed to `__next__`, of course.)

Answer (score 0):

`__iter__()` is intended to return an iterator over the object. What is an iterator over an object that is already an iterator? `self`, of course.

Comment: An iterator is an iterator over whatever it's an iterator over, not over itself, in the same way a list contains other values, not (necessarily) itself. Anyway, why should `iter(an_iterator)` even be defined? Why does it *have* to be defined? (There are good reasons, but you don't name any).