# What's the point of the iter() built-in?

Tags: python

With `iter()`, I can do this:

```
>>> listWalker = iter ( [23, 47, 'hike'] )
>>> for x in listWalker: print x,
```

But I could do this anyway:

```
>>> listWalker = [23, 47, 'hike']
>>> for x in listWalker: print x,
```

What value does it add?

Comment: There's a great example of using `iter` [here](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2233204/how-does-zipitersn-work-in-python).

Comment: Related: [Why does a Python Iterator need an iter method that simply returns self?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/21343327/why-does-a-python-iterator-need-an-iter-method-that-simply-returns-self)

Comment: Actually, that "related" question has a spot-on top-voted answer. I'm leaning to agree with the vote to close.

Comment: @CharlesDuffy This is not a duplicate. The linked question asked why `iter(some_iterator)` works. This question asks why there **is** an `iter` function in the first place (when `for` does the job anyway). The two are not the same.

Comment: @user4815162342, the questions indeed aren't the same, but the answers are entirely applicable.

Comment: @CharlesDuffy The accepted/top-voted answer doesn't appear applicable at all. It explains what `iter` *does* without explaining what would be the *point* of needing to do that. (It also explains why `iter` needs `__iter__`, which is even less relevant for this question.)

Comment: Since my initial vote-to-close, some much better (and on-point) answers have turned up here, so I'm inclined to agree that it was in error.

Answer (score 6):

In addition to using `iter` to explicitly get an iterator for an object that implements the `__iter__` method, there is the lesser-known two-argument form of `iter`, which makes an iterator which repeatedly calls a function until it returns a given sentinel value.

```
 for line in iter(f.readline, 'EOF'):
     print line
```

The preceding code would call `f.read` (for, say, an open file handle `f`) until it reads a line consisting of the string `EOF`. It's roughly the same as writing

```
for line in f:
    if line == "EOF":
        break
    print line
```

Additionally, an iterator may be a distinct object from the object it iterates over. This is true for the `list` type. That means you can create two iterators, both of which iterate *independently* over the same object.

```
itr1 = iter(mylist)
itr2 = iter(mylist)

x = next(itr1)   # First item of mylist
y = next(itr1)   # Second item of my list
z = next(itr2)   # First item of mylist, not the third
```

File handles, however, act as their own iterator:

```
>>> f = open('.bashrc')
>>> id(f)
4454569712
>>> id(iter(f))
4454569712
```

In general, the object returned by `iter` depends on the `__iter__` method implemented by the object's type.

Comment: +1 Excellent answer, covering both "normal" usage of `iter` and the two-argument form. You might want to be more precise by stating that an iterator **can** be a distinct object from the object it iterates over. Many objects, most notably file objects, but also iterators themselves, are their own iterators.

Answer (score 5):

The point of `iter` is that it allows you to obtain the iterator from an iterable object and use it yourself, either to implement your own variant of the `for` loop, or to maintain the state of the iteration across multiple loops. A trivial example:

```
it = iter(['HEADER', 0, 1, 2, 3])  # coming from CSV or such
title = it.next()
for item in it:
    # process item
    ...
```

A more advanced usage of `iter` is provided by this grouping idiom:

```
def in_groups(iterable, n):
    """Yield element from iterables grouped in tuples of size n."""
    it = iter(iterable)
    iters = [it] * n
    return zip(*iters)
```

Comment: +1 Very nice, *practical* example of creating multiple iterators of the same iterable.

Answer (score 0):

When you're doing a `for` loop on a variable, it implicitly call the  `__iter__` method of the iterable you passed in fact.
You're always using `iter()` is some way when you're looping over lists, tuples... and every iterable.

I think this extract of byte-code can convince you:

```
>>> def a():
...     for x in [1,2,3]:
...         print x
...
>>> import dis
>>> dis.dis(a)
  2           0 SETUP_LOOP              28 (to 31)
              3 LOAD_CONST               1 (1)
              6 LOAD_CONST               2 (2)
              9 LOAD_CONST               3 (3)
             12 BUILD_LIST               3
             15 GET_ITER                                 # <--- get iter is important here
        >>   16 FOR_ITER                11 (to 30)
             19 STORE_FAST               0 (x)

  3          22 LOAD_FAST                0 (x)
             25 PRINT_ITEM
             26 PRINT_NEWLINE
             27 JUMP_ABSOLUTE           16
        >>   30 POP_BLOCK
        >>   31 LOAD_CONST               0 (None)
             34 RETURN_VALUE
```

---

But, iterables allows you also some other things in Python, such as the use of `next()` to walk into an iterable, or raising a [`StopIteration` exception](http://docs.python.org/2/library/exceptions.html#exceptions.StopIteration). It can be useful if you're dealing with different object types and you want to apply a generic algorithm.

Answer (score 0):

From [the docs](http://docs.python.org/2/library/functions.html#iter):

> iter(o[, sentinel])
>
> [...] Without a second argument, o must be a collection object which supports the
>   iteration protocol (the `__iter__()` method), or it must support the
>   sequence protocol (the `__getitem__()` method with integer arguments
>   starting at 0). If it does not support either of those protocols,
>   TypeError is raised. [...]

So it constructs an iterator from an object.

As you say, this is done automatically in loops and comprehensions but some times you want to get an iterator and handle it directly. Just keep it in the back of your mind until you need it.

When using the second argument:

> If the second argument, *sentinel*, is given, then o must be a callable object. 
>   The iterator created in this case will call o with no arguments for each call 
>   to its next() method; if the value returned is equal to sentinel, 
>   StopIteration will be raised, otherwise the value will be returned.

This is useful for many things but particularly so for legacy style functions like `file.read(bufsize)` which has to be called repeatedly until it returns `""`. That can be converted to an iterator with `iter(lambda : file.read(bufsize), "")`. Nice and clean!